# ifup wlan0 causes kernel Oops

Tags: kernel, wifi, linux-kernel, dmesg

on my laptop, when I do `ifup wlan0`, sometimes I get following call trace in `dmesg`. Other times, the log looks perfectly normal, and there are no `kernel Oops` messages.

In both cases (with errors and without), my network seems to work fine.

But I would like to understand what is happening. Could somebody please help me interpret the meaning of the call trace messages ?

```
kernel: [181794.747548] ------------[ cut here ]------------
kernel: [181794.747560] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 8430 at net/wireless/reg.c:1806 0xffffffff8147a677()
kernel: [181794.747570] CPU: 2 PID: 8430 Comm: kworker/2:0 Tainted: G        W     3.16.6 #1
kernel: [181794.747574] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Latitude E7440/03HFCG, BIOS A09 05/01/2014
kernel: [181794.747579] Workqueue: events 0xffffffff8147a740
kernel: [181794.747584]  0000000000000000 0000000000000009 ffffffff814c43fb 0000000000000000
kernel: [181794.747592]  ffffffff81058185 0000000000011500 ffffffff8147a677 ffff88040d4cb300
kernel: [181794.747598]  ffff8804082e7e00 0000000000000003 ffff88040d440240 ffff8804082e7e00
kernel: [181794.747605] Call Trace:
kernel: [181794.747611]  [<ffffffff814c43fb>] ? 0xffffffff814c43fb
kernel: [181794.747615]  [<ffffffff81058185>] ? 0xffffffff81058185
kernel: [181794.747619]  [<ffffffff8147a677>] ? 0xffffffff8147a677
kernel: [181794.747623]  [<ffffffff8147a677>] ? 0xffffffff8147a677
kernel: [181794.747627]  [<ffffffff8147a7ae>] ? 0xffffffff8147a7ae
kernel: [181794.747630]  [<ffffffff81067c27>] ? 0xffffffff81067c27
kernel: [181794.747634]  [<ffffffff8106806f>] ? 0xffffffff8106806f
kernel: [181794.747638]  [<ffffffff81067d7d>] ? 0xffffffff81067d7d
kernel: [181794.747642]  [<ffffffff8106cc2d>] ? 0xffffffff8106cc2d
kernel: [181794.747645]  [<ffffffff8106cb68>] ? 0xffffffff8106cb68
kernel: [181794.747649]  [<ffffffff814cb16c>] ? 0xffffffff814cb16c
kernel: [181794.747653]  [<ffffffff8106cb68>] ? 0xffffffff8106cb68
kernel: [181794.747657] ---[ end trace 269bc2d623c15a61 ]---
kernel: [181794.747661] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DE
kernel: [181794.790714] CPU: 2 PID: 8430 Comm: kworker/2:0 Tainted: G        W     3.16.6 #1
kernel: [181794.790717] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Latitude E7440/03HFCG, BIOS A09 05/01/2014
kernel: [181794.790720] Workqueue: events 0xffffffff8147a740
kernel: [181794.790723]  0000000000000000 0000000000000009 ffffffff814c43fb 0000000000000000
kernel: [181794.790728]  ffffffff81058185 0000000000011500 ffffffff8147a677 ffff88040d4cb300
kernel: [181794.790732]  ffff8804082e7e00 0000000000000003 ffff88040d440240 ffff8804082e7e00
kernel: [181794.790736] Call Trace:
kernel: [181794.790740]  [<ffffffff814c43fb>] ? 0xffffffff814c43fb
kernel: [181794.790743]  [<ffffffff81058185>] ? 0xffffffff81058185
kernel: [181794.790745]  [<ffffffff8147a677>] ? 0xffffffff8147a677
kernel: [181794.790747]  [<ffffffff8147a677>] ? 0xffffffff8147a677
kernel: [181794.790750]  [<ffffffff8147a7ae>] ? 0xffffffff8147a7ae
kernel: [181794.790752]  [<ffffffff81067c27>] ? 0xffffffff81067c27
kernel: [181794.790754]  [<ffffffff8106806f>] ? 0xffffffff8106806f
kernel: [181794.790757]  [<ffffffff81067d7d>] ? 0xffffffff81067d7d
kernel: [181794.790759]  [<ffffffff8106cc2d>] ? 0xffffffff8106cc2d
kernel: [181794.790761]  [<ffffffff8106cb68>] ? 0xffffffff8106cb68
kernel: [181794.790763]  [<ffffffff814cb16c>] ? 0xffffffff814cb16c
kernel: [181794.790766]  [<ffffffff8106cb68>] ? 0xffffffff8106cb68
kernel: [181794.790768] ---[ end trace 269bc2d623c15a62 ]---
kernel: [181794.790771] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DE
kernel: [181794.972483] ------------[ cut here ]------------
```

For completion, I might add that this is a new laptop, but I have replaced the original wifi card (Intel Dualband Wireless-AC 7260) with my own card (Intel Centrino Ultimate-N 6300)

I am using Debian Wheezy with my own kernel 3.16.6

Comment: [Submit a bug report](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/lkml/reporting-bugs.html).

Comment: For reference, here is the line of code generating this warning: [net/wireless/reg.c:1806](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/wireless/reg.c?v=3.16#L1806).  The comment reads `Two consecutive Country IE hints on the same wiphy. This should be picked up early by the driver/stack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be a false warning.

To quote from the (now closed) [kernel bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89001):

> Alfred Krohmer: If I unterstand your patch correctly it just removes the warning, but it won't actually fix the driver crash this bug report was submitted for. So why mark it as resolved?
>
> Emmanuel Grumbach: There is no real bug. The [commit message](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/5417441/) explains this.

Well, I see the same error in dmesg but my Wifi connections works fine. (I'm using a Lenovo Thinkpad W540.) Interestingly, the [Arch Linux bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/index.php?do=details&task_id=41906) is still open, and some say that the have connection problems.